# Sharepoint Website Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, permissions

I am running SharePoint 2016 on premise. My company is using this as the website engine. I have designed the website and all, but I realize that trying to browse to the website from an external browser always prompts me to login.

What settings do I have to change to make this website accessible to anonymous visitors? I have fiddled with some settings like the Anonymous Access rights, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have two steps to allow anonymous Access to your SharePoint Site

- At **Central Administration** > Manage web applications > Select your web application > from the above ribbon select authentication provider > Click on Default > Check `Enable anonymous access`

[image]

- At your **site Collection** > Site Settings > Users and Permissions > Site Permission >  at the above ribbon > select `anonymes aceess` > Select `Entire Web Site`

Comment: Thanks for you advice thus far. I am curious though...is there anything else that I need to do. I have done all that you prescribed and still have to login when I attempt to browse to the site from an external resource.

Do I need to modify Windows Authentication or Forms Based Authentication options?

Comment: Dear @trevoirwilliams , first Make sure that master page and layout and image files are checked in and published as a major version , also use fiddler to trace that http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/anton_staykov/archive/2010/08/24/how-to-debug-your-application-http-protocol-using-fiddler.aspx ,  also you can send to me the URL of your site to check it from  my side as anonymous user  , please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification ,

Comment: Thanks for the offer. Challenge with allowing you to test it is that it is currently not published for access via the internet. I will test it with fiddler and try to ascertain the fallacies accordingly. I will let you know my findings.